# Inconsistency regarding plural: why do we write "results file" but also "result list"?

Tags: grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

How come it is ok to write "result**s** file",
while you must write "result list" rather than "result**s** list"?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with "results list". "Results" may imply things that are achieved successfully. Please check dictionaries.

Comment: *Results* is one of few nouns where you can pluralize it when you put it in front of list. [See Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=result+list%2Cresults+list&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cresult%20list%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresults%20list%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, either version is grammatically correct. However, the word "list" implies a plural amount of the item, therefore stylistically people only use a singular in front of "list". However, the word "file" does not imply a plural amount (technically you could have a file with only one result), so you can use plural form in order to clarify.